IEnumerable dependency property not working as expected
I have a user Control that looks like this,
<ItemsControl x:Name="_opt" ItemsSource="{Binding Sources, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>           
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>

I have created a IEnumerable dependency property called sources somewhat like this,
public IEnumerable Sources
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SourcesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SourcesProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SourcesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Sources", typeof(IEnumerable),
        typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

My usercontrol constructor looks like this, I'm assigning Itemsource here too,
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

The problem that I'm facing is when I assign a list of string to Sources property it shows nothing, but If i set the Itemsource directly to that list of string, I can do that.
Now I can set list of string in the usercontrol but if I'm using usercontrol somewhere, there I can set the Itemsource and that the reason I created an IEnumerable.
This is how I'm using my Usercontrol,
<local:MyUserControl x:Name="_uc"/>

public NewControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _uc.Sources = MyListofString;
}

No matter what I try, whenever I bind or assign the list, it doesn't show any item. I'm I made the property correctly still can't wrap my head around onto why this not updating.

The Sources property has not yet been set in the MyUserControl constructor. You have to register a PropertyChangedCallback. Alternatively, bind the property like <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Sources, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">

I tried this, but it didn't work.

It is also unclear whether MyListofString already contains some elements when you assign _uc.Sources = MyListofString;. If elements are added later, MyListofString should be an ObservableCollection.

It Contains elements, it is more like List Mylist = new List(){"a","b","c"};

yes, I'm sorry, I forgot to edit that part

The code you are showing now is ok. When the control does not show any items, the error must be somewhere else.

any suggestion what could be the problem?

@prabhaat That's why I was asking "whether MyListofString already contains some elements when you assign _uc.Sources = MyListofString;". That was apparently not the case. And you did not show us the relevant parts of your actual code.

@Clemens Deleting comments? Yes, I know. I was thinking about it, but I did not try to hide my mistake. I am not afraid of it too much. Also, it thought it would look confusing if I deleted my comment and you did not. At the same time, my question and your answer only contaminate the discussion and are redundant, so removing this part of the comments would be useful. Will you do it? Then I'm deleting. Thank you again for pointing out my mistake.

I resolved it by using ObservableCollection instead of List.
Still not sure why List was not working.
